# ¿Por qué mi código no compila?

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto usando processing. Estoy estancado por un error que me da y no logro encontrarle solución. El error es el siguiente

[image: Error]

Este es mi constructor

```
public Robot1(PApplet p, int colour, float xPos, float yPos, float xSpeed) {
    parent = p;
    this.colour=colour;
    this.xPos= xPos;
    this.yPos= yPos;
    this.xSpeed=xSpeed;
}
```

Este es mi método setup

```
public void setup() {
    robots = new Robot[2];
    robots [0] = new Robot(this, colour(255, 0, 0), (float)(width/4),(float)(height/4), 1f);
    //Robot2 [1] = new Robot(colour (0,255,0), (float)(3* width/4), (float)(3*height/4, 1));
}
```

este es el número error

[image: Error 2]

La parte del código donde creo que hay algo mal

```
public void display() {
    parent.fill(color);
    parent.triangle(30, 75, 58, 20, 86, 75);
}
```

Comment: Hola @EdgardoQuintero, no deberías de modificar la pregunta para agregar el nuevo error. Deberías de crear una pregunta nueva para preguntar por ese nuevo error ya que si no de esta manera las respuestas que hemos dado para el error anterior pierden su validez. Vuelvo a poner la pregunta tal y como estaba antes para que no tengas que volverla a escribir (no sé si con tu puntuación te dejan hacer rollback). En caso contrario, si fuese sobre el mismo error añadir información adicional entonces sí que deberías añadir la información en esta pregunta.

Comment: bueno creo q ahora voy entendiendo como editar y usar los comentarios de verdad disculpa y gracias por la ayuda !!!

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes definida la variable parent?

Comment: la tengo definida de la siguiente manera PApplet parent; junto con las variables de la clase Robot1

Comment: Realmente en la te indica en que línea está el error (clase RobotLab1 línea 25). Mira a ver lo que hay en esa línea ya que el error que te está dando es que estás intentando acceder a un método de un objeto que es nulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos errores en tu código:

- El primero es que estás llamando al constructor de la clase `Robot` en vez de `Robot1`.
- El segundo es que tendrías que llamar al método `color` en vez de `colour`.

Según la API el método es:

```
public final int color(float v1,
                       float v2,
                       float v3)
```

Comment: ya corregi ambos errores aun asi sigo sin ver el triangulo(Robot en pantalla)

Comment: @EdgardoQuintero ¿Te da algún tipo de error?

Comment: si, se habe la ventana no se ve nada y me aparece el siguiente error en linea de comando

Comment: pero creo q tiene q ver con otro metodo :( q es el de display()

Comment: @EdgardoQuintero ¿A que error te refieres? Y deberías de editar tu pregunta para añadir la información que has añadido en tu respuesta. Las respuestas se deben utilizar solo para intentar resolver la pregunta pero no para añadir información. Gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

El método es color, no colour, si veo el [API](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/index.html?processing/core/PApplet.html) correctamente.

Comment: Pablo Muchas gracias si era eso, aunque el codigo corre no me esta mostrando el robot que en este caso es un triangulo no se si tenga q ver con las coordenadas en las q estoy inicilizando el robot y me da un error q nunk habia visto en la linea de comando